# ELM language Just trying to get the package install command to work to bring in html

Tags: elm

I am in windows, when I go to the command prompt and type elm package install elm-lang/html   I get the message "There is no package command"     I have no idea why, my other elm commands work in this command prompt.

Comment: Try `elm --help`. It's just `elm install elm-lang/html`, in recent version at least.

Comment: @glennsl Almost. It's `elm install elm/html` in elm 0.19.x

Answer (score 1):

There is missing a `-` in your command. Depending on your version, you should use:

`elm-package install elm-lang/html`

or if in the latest version:

`elm install elm/html`